# gran duda sobre genericos en typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, genericos

Estoy aprendiendo typescript y acabo de entrar al tema de genericos, todo estaba bien pero encontre un ejemplo que no logro entender. En la siguiente imagen como es que typescript sabe que los parametros genericos de la funcion "compare" son <number, string>?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supuestamente estos tipos se infieren de los argumentos que se envian por lo tanto llamar a la funcion se deberia ver asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro comprenderlo. Otra cosa que note es que parece que toma los tipos del primer argumento porque si  el segundo objeto tiene tipos distintos me mostrara un error como en esta imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero me puedan ayudar. Les deseo un excelente dia a todos.

Comment: Qué tal Daniel, bienvenido a SO. Te invito a realizar el [tour] y ganar tu primera medalla. Adicionalmente te comento que si vas a incluir código, lo hagas en texto ya que el código en imagen no es bien recibido. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta en cualquier momento.

Comment: Comparte el código _como texto, con formato_, pulsando en el botón que indica `{}`.

Comment: Añade el mensaje de error que obtienes por favor